# (Python flask) Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, response

Пытаюсь сделать приложение по этому уроку,

https://www.codementor.io/@olawalealadeusi896/restful-api-with-python-flask-framework-and-postgres-db-part-1-kbrwbygx5

но сталкиваюсь с проблемой. И так как я новичек в питоне, то я не могу понять в чем причина этой ошибки.

```
from flask import request, json, jsonify, Response, Blueprint, g
from ..models.UserModel import UserModel, UserSchema
from ..shared.Authentication import Auth

user_api = Blueprint('users', __name__)
user_schema = UserSchema()


@user_api.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    data = user_schema.load(req_data)

    if 'error' in data:
        return custom_response(data.get('error'), 400)

    user_in_db = UserModel.get_user_by_email(data.get('email'))
    if user_in_db:
        message = {'error': 'User already exist, please supply anotehr email addres'}
        return custom_response(message, 400)

    user = UserModel(data)
    user.save()

    ser_data = user_schema.dump(user)
    token = Auth.generate_token(ser_data.get('id'))

    return custom_response({'jwt_token': token}, 201)


@user_api.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@Auth.auth_required
def get_all():
    users = UserModel.get_all_users()
    ser_users = user_schema.dump(users, many=True)
    return custom_response(ser_users, 200)


@user_api.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    req_data = request.get_json()

    data, error = user_schema.load(req_data, partial=True)

    if error:
        return custom_response(error, 400)

    if not data.get('email') or not data.get('password'):
        return custom_response({'error': 'you need email and password to sign in'}, 400)

    user = UserModel.get_user_by_email(data.get('email'))

    if not user:
        return custom_response({'error': 'invalid credentials'}, 400)

    if not user.check_hash(data.get('password')):
        return custom_response({'error': 'invalid credentials'}, 400)

    ser_data = user_schema.dump(user)

    token = Auth.generate_token(ser_data.get('id'))

    return custom_response({'jwt_token': token}, 200)


@user_api.route('/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])
@Auth.auth_required
def get_a_user(user_id):
    user = UserModel.get_one_user(user_id)
    if not user:
        return custom_response({'error': 'user not found'}, 404)

    ser_user = user_schema.dump(user)
    return custom_response(ser_user, 200)


@user_api.route('/me', methods=['PUT'])
@Auth.auth_required
def update():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    data, error = user_schema.load(req_data, partial=True)
    if error:
        return custom_response(error, 400)

    user = UserModel.get_one_user(g.user.get('id'))
    user.update(data)
    ser_user = user_schema.dump(user)
    return custom_response(ser_user, 200)


@user_api.route('/me', methods=['DELETE'])
@Auth.auth_required
def delete():
    user = UserModel.get_one_user(g.user.get('id'))
    user.delete()
    return custom_response({'message': 'deleted'}, 204)


@user_api.route('/me', methods=['GET'])
@Auth.auth_required
def get_me():
    user = UserModel.get_one_user(g.user.get('id'))
    ser_user = user_schema.dump(user)
    return custom_response(ser_user, 200)


def custom_response(res, status_code):
    return Response(
        mimetype="application/json",
        response=json.dumps(res),
        status=status_code
    )
```

получаю ошибку как в названии.

Вот трейс бек, если он имеет значение

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/jebbyk/Desktop/git/OmSTU/5-th sem/blog_rest/src/views/UserView.py", line 28, in create
    return custom_response({'jwt_token': token}, 201)
  File "/home/jebbyk/Desktop/git/OmSTU/5-th sem/blog_rest/src/views/UserView.py", line 110, in custom_response
    response=json.dumps(res),
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 211, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/jebbyk/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog_rest-pkqspueH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 100, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Смотрите значение переменной token

Answer (score 1):

> > Вот трейс бек, если он имеет значение

Он имеет значение, ведь без него сложно понять где именно ошибка.

Смотрите в нем ваши скрипты, например тут:

```
...
  File "/home/jebbyk/Desktop/git/OmSTU/5-th sem/blog_rest/src/views/UserView.py", line 28, in create
    return custom_response({'jwt_token': token}, 201)
  File "/home/jebbyk/Desktop/git/OmSTU/5-th sem/blog_rest/src/views/UserView.py", line 110, in custom_response
    response=json.dumps(res),
...
```

Я могу сказать, что проблема была в функции `create`, когда вызвали `custom_response`, а ошибка случилась в `custom_response` в строке `response=json.dumps(res)` при сериализации данных в строку `JSON`, о чем и говорит исключение `TypeError: Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable`.

Уверен, что проблема связана с:

```
token = Auth.generate_token(ser_data.get('id'))
return custom_response({'jwt_token': token}, 200)
```

Т.к. объект в `token` не является стандартным питоничьим объектом типа, т.е. `json` не может его сериализовать в свой объект (`число`, `строка`, `список`, `словарь`, `null`, ...)

Не знаю, что делает `Auth.generate_token`, но попробуйте из `token` вытащить само его значение

---

**UPD.**

Нашел [код](https://gist.github.com/olawalejarvis/cf02f37653ff6a63008a915b7a757276#file-authentication0-py) по которому работает автор. Код выполняет двуякую работу и при определенном условии ломает код примера, что очень странно, поэтому предлагаю сделать некоторую доработку:

```
  @staticmethod
  def generate_token(user_id):
    """
    Generate Token Method
    """
    try:
      payload = {
        'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        'sub': user_id
      }
      return jwt.encode(
        payload,
        os.getenv('JWT_SECRET_KEY'),
        'HS256'
      ).decode("utf-8")
    except Exception as e:
      return Response(
        mimetype="application/json",
        response=json.dumps({'error': 'error in generating user token'}),
        status=400
      )
```

По нему я вижу, что по хорошему метод `generate_token` должен вернуть строку (`.decode("utf-8")` может только к байтам применяться, чтобы получить строку в указанной кодировке), но вернет `Response` в случаи проблемы с генерацией.

Поэтому, предлагаю сделать доработку:

```
token = Auth.generate_token(ser_data.get('id'))
if isinstance(token, Response):
    return token

return custom_response({'jwt_token': token}, 200)
```

А в `generate_token` добавить вывод ошибки хотя бы в консоль:

```
import traceback
...

    except Exception as e:
      print(traceback.format_exc())

      return Response(
        mimetype="application/json",
        response=json.dumps({'error': 'error in generating user token'}),
        status=400
      )
```

Тогда, понятно будет в чем ошибка и как ее исправить, чтобы получить токен.

Comment: Да вы правы, проблема была в Auth.generate_token. Правда я так и не понял почему такая проблема возникла. В туторе в качестве ответа пишут return Response(blablalblalbalb) но так почему то не работает. Пишет не сериалайзбл. Зато когда я поменял Response на jsonify все заработало. В туторе про это ни слова

Comment: Правда есть одно но. Таким образом в моем случае в качестве ответа приходит не то что нужно.  mimetype и status записываются в качестве ключей в джейсонку. А сам статус выставляется дефолтным (200) что не совсем то что я хотел.

Comment: @владимирзайцев, вы ведь этим `{'jwt_token': token}` хотели вернуть json с токеном, типа: `{'jwt_token': 'dabc23213acbd'}`? А `Auth.generate_token` должен был и сгенерировать токен? Я кое-что нашел и дополню ответ